# Performance impact with calculations in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

We are using MySQL table with below query (With arithmetic calculation). Query is selecting correct results according to where clause logic (Pretty fast with few records).

```
select phone_number
from user
where (wdd_lat - 10)*(wdd_lat - 10) + (wdd_lon - 20)*(wdd_lon - 20) <= 25;

phone_number, wdd_lat, wdd_lon
0777453637,34,30
0432432333,245,56
4141411414,45,125
1232341444,56,25
1111111111,78,90
```

But We are bit worried about the performance in latter run.

1. Once table grows considerably large, will it provide results quickly? (When record count around 1 million)
2. How can we improve performance, if it delay in providing results?
3. Is there any other methods to improve performance when the table grows (Any suggestion outside DB/sql also welcome)

Comment: If you care about performance, you will need to look at GIS extensions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any recommended links to follow?

Comment: Maybe you can replace this search using some search engine like Elasticsearch, it will be pretty fast with searching distance between coordinates, I have a DB with ~3 million of rows, and a coordinate search like yours takes less then 50ms

Comment: Thanks Elias for your suggestion. We are bit familiar with ELK stack. Will give it a try.